# ¿Por qué no me funciona este constructor?

Tags: java, poo, netbeans, class

He creado un programa para almacenar datos que se piden por teclado, para luego crear un objeto de la clase `Vehiculo` con los datos pedidos en otra clase llamada `Principal`.

Todo funciona bien y si meto los datos pedidos por teclado con el método `setter` que he creado, todo funciona correctamente.

Pero para que fuese más elegante (o eso pienso) he creado un constructor de la clase vehículo en el cual le paso todos los parámetros para que se cree de una vez.

El problema es que si le paso los parámetros por el constructor, todos los valores de sus variables se quedan a null.

¿Sabéis por qué puede ser?

```
coche = new Vehiculo (marca, matricula, numKms, fechaMatriculacion, descripcion, precio, nombrePropietario, dniPropietario);
```

Este es el constructor que no funciona.

Sin embargo de esta forma, todo funciona correctamente:

```
if (todoCreado) {
                    coche = new Vehiculo();
                    coche.setMarca(marca);
                    coche.setMatricula(matricula);
                    coche.setFechaMatriculacion(fechaMatriculacion);
                    coche.setNumKms(numKms);
                    coche.setDescripcion(descripcion);
                    coche.setPrecio(precio);
                    coche.setNombrePropietario(nombrePropietario);
                    coche.setDniPropietario(dniPropietario);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El objeto coche ha sido creado satisfactoriamente");
                    
                    // Pinta por pantalla los datos introducidos para comprobar el buen funcionamiento del programa.
                    System.out.println(coche.getMarca());
                    System.out.println(coche.getMatricula());
                    System.out.println(coche.getNumKms());
                    System.out.println(coche.getFechaMatriculacion());
                    System.out.println(coche.getDescripcion());
                    System.out.println(coche.getPrecio());
                    System.out.println(coche.getNombrePropietario());
                    System.out.println(coche.getDniPropietario());
                }
```

Os paso la clase Vehiculo:

```
public class Vehiculo {                     // Clase vehículo

private String marca;                           // Variable que indica la marca del vehículo.
private String matricula;                       // Variable que indica la matrícula del vehículo.
private Double numKms;                          // Variable que indica el número de Kms.
private LocalDate fechaMatriculacion;           // Variable que indica la fecha de matriculación del vehículo. 
private String descripcion;                     // Variable que indica una descripción del vehículo. Datos adicionales.
private Integer precio;                         // Variable que indica el precio del vehículo.
private String nombrePropietario;               // Variable que indica el nombre del propietario del vehículo.
private String dniPropietario;                  // Variable que indica el DNI del propietario del vehículo.

public Vehiculo () {                        // Constructor vacío.
    
}

public Vehiculo (String marca, String matricula, double numKms, LocalDate fechaMatriculacion, String descripcion, 
        int precio, String nombrePropietario, String dniPropietario) {                  // Constructor pasando parámetros.
    
}
```

Gracias. Un saludo.

Comment: te falta usar this en el constructor con parametros,se supone que debes asociar las variables private a los datos que estas pasando como parametro,pór esi te arroja null

Comment: Tu constructor está vacío. Java no sabe que debe hacer con los parámetros. Tienes que indicarlo tu mismo.

Answer (score 1):

un constructor con parametros debes estar asociado a las variables que tienes como private ,para que esas capturen los datos que pases como parametro al momento de crear una nueva instancia de esa clase,ya que no haces uso de los setters.el uso de this es como decir oye el dato marca que le paso como parametro va a ser igual a la variable marca que tengo como private

```
public Vehiculo (String marca, String matricula, double numKms, LocalDate fechaMatriculacion, String descripcion, 
        int precio, String nombrePropietario, String dniPropietario) {  

            this.marca=marca;
            this.matricula=matricula;
            this.numKms=numKms;
            this.fechaMatriculacion=fechaMatriculacion;
            this.descripcion=descripcion;
            this.precio=precio;
            this nombrePropietario=nombrePropietario;
            this.dniPropietario=dniPropietario;            
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. La verdad es que no controlo muy bien el tema de los constructores como te habrás dado cuenta :(

Answer (score 0):

> No tiene metodo main ademas uso incorrecto del constructor

```js
import java.util.Date;


public class Vehiculo {                     

  private String marca;                          
  private String matricula;    
  
   // crear metodo main 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date now = new Date();
   Vehiculo nuevo = new Vehiculo("Ford","OA1258");
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    System.out.println("marca: " + nuevo.marca);
    System.out.println("modelo: " + nuevo.matricula );
    Vehiculo supe= new Vehiculo("BMW","ww897");
    System.out.println("marca: " + supe.marca);
    System.out.println("modelo: " + supe.matricula );
     supe.setMarca("Fiat");
     System.out.println("Modifico marca: " + supe.getMarca());
     
}
  /*
  compilador crea un constructor vacío sino se escribe uno explícitamente
  public Vehiculo () {                        
      
  }*/
  
  public Vehiculo (String marca, String matricula ) {                  
      this.matricula=matricula;
      this.marca=marca;
  }
  
  public String getMarca() {
         return marca;
  }
  public void setMarca (String marca){
        this.marca = marca;
    }
}
```